# Openlayers - Draw String on Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, gis, openstreetmap

Im trying to draw a String/Character on a layer in Openlayers (eg displaying a Route --> draw description or floor number near the Route).
Problem: It is possible to add a Label to a Openlayers.Vector, but my Application has one Vector with multiple geometries in it, which should be rendered with a different String each.
Maybe there exists some Geometry like this: layer.addFeature(new Openlayers.StringGeometry("text", x,y) or so. I couldnt find anything.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add custom text label to the features of Vector layer, I suggest the following:

1) add `StyleMap` to your Vector layer as such:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector", 
{
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(            
    {
        label : "${labelText}",                    
        fontColor: "blue",
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        labelAlign: "lc",
        labelXOffset: "14",
        labelYOffset: "0",
        labelOutlineColor: "white",
        labelOutlineWidth: 3
    })
});
```

note that `labelText` in this style map says that text for this label will be taken from corresponding feature attribute.

2) For each feature you add to your layer specify the attributes having `labelText` defined:

```
var features = [];
var pt = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0);
features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pt, {labelText: "This is my label"}));
vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);
```

The only limitation with this solution is that you will have to add feature for each point and not able to use `OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint`.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking it as answer if this solved your problem :)